# WIN32 Console App -> CLR problems with threads

Tags: c++, clr

I have change my win32 console application c++ project into project that could handled windows form, so i switched into CLR.

I have problems with threads, specially with concurrent queue.

In my .h class i have:

```
#include <concurrent_queue.h>
...
concurrent_queue<unsigned char*> queue;\
```

In .cpp for example:

```
queue.try_pop(record)
```

There I have errors:

```
ERROR: Concurrency Runtime is not supported when compiling /clr.
```

I know that I must change my current queue with something else, but i don't know into what, and how.

Can You please help me? I searched on stack, but I don't know how to change this queue.

Comment: Not going to work. Treat /CLR as essentially a deprecated option. You should not be developing new WinForms applications in C++.

Comment: @CodyGray unfortunately i must

Comment: Hard to imagine how you would ever get yourself into a situation where you "must". There are lots of other ways to implement a UI in C++. Either way, if you must, then you'll need to use something other than the concurrency runtime to implement threads.

Comment: @CodyGray I tried implement UI in C++ in other way's, but none worked fine. One way is probably using dialogs in WIN32, but the dialog's are really old, and they don't have component's that I want to use in my project. I tried with clr but this fails. Do You have some good advice for me? How should i add UI to this?

Comment: There isn't enough information in that comment for me to make suggestions. I use Win32 to develop apps all the time. The dialogs aren't "old". You can do anything in Win32 that you can do using the .NET Framework. Maybe if you gave a specific example of a control that you needed? Beware, though, that SO does not really do "recommendation" questions. Another popular C++ UI library for those who feel that Win32 is too low-level is Qt. There are tons of others; use Google to find them. The error message already tells you what the problem is: the concurrency runtime isn't supported with CLR.